# Local storage 3 objects

Tags: javascript

It is possible to add **3 objects** to Local storage , not only value and key ? I tried some codes but not work.

I want:

1. 3 objects
2. 3 input text
3. save button which save text on page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. `localStorage` (and `sessionStorage`) can store only key-value pairs, where values can only be *strings*.

The best you can do is to store plain objects, using some serialization algorhythm. JSON is the most common, so you can use `JSON.stringify` to convert an object to a string, an `JSON.parse` to convert it back to an object - which will *not* be the "same" (i.e. a reference to the same data), but something *equivalent*.

Which mean that this happens:

```
var a = {value: 5},
    j = JSON.stringify(a);

var b = a,
    c = JSON.parse(j);

a.value = 7;
b.value;   // 7
c.value;   // 5
```

But this doesn't work with DOM elements anyway. They can't be stored, period. Just like any other object of any class that's not `Object`, unless they provide a `toJSON` method that reliably convert them to strings, which can eventually be parsed back.

The `toJSON` method is internally used by `JSON.stringify` to convert objects to strings.

`Date` objects provide a `toJSON` method, for example. You can convert the strings back using `Date.parse`:

```
var d = new Date(),
    j = d.toJSON(); // e.g. "2014-02-22T10:35:41.579Z"

var o = new Date(Date.parse(j));

o.getTime() === d.getTime(); // true
o === d;                     // false
```

(Keep in mind that JSON isn't natively supported by IE7 and lower.)

You can't do the same for DOM elements, though, so 2 and 3 are not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly, no. You can only store key/values of the type **string.**

But, you've to take a look at: [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

They explain a workaround by stringify the object.

Quote of CMS(accepted answer):

```
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```